# Providing an example function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Give an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ for which the function $f(tx,ty)$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, has a local minimum at $t = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $g(0) = 0$ is a local minimum and $g(1)<0$. Define $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ by

$$f(x, y) = g(kx) \text{ if } x=ky,\  k\in \mathbb N$$

and $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ otherwise. Then $f$ satisfies the condition and $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum: for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $1/k^2 + 1/k^4<\epsilon^2$. Thus

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k^2} \bigg) \in B_\epsilon\big((0,0)\big)\text{ and } f(\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k^2}) = g(1)<0 = f(0,0)\ .$$

Comment: Can you explain why your proposed function satisfies the condition that $f(tx,ty)$ has a local minimum at $t = 0$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @DavidSmith: Note that apart from the line $x=ky$, the function is just $x^2 + y^2$, which is zero only when $(x, y) = 0$. While on the lines $x = ky$, it is defined as a function which has a minimum at $0$ ($g(kx)$ has a local min at $0$ for all $k$).

Comment: So why is it the case that $tx \neq 1/k$ and $ty \neq 1/k^2$.  In other words, it seems to me that your proof involving $f(1/k,1/k^2)$, etc., must only pertain to $f(x,y)$, but not to $f(tx,ty)$?

Comment: The point $(1/k, 1/k^2)$ lies in the line $x = ky$. So may think of the following: if $x = ky$ is a fixed point, then $f(tx, ty) = f(kty, ty) = g(kty)$. This function has a local minimum at $t=0$ and when $t = 1/ky$, $g(tky) = g(1)<0$